# how do I get backup for my laptop and do I need to pay for that?

Tags: backup

I need to backup my laptop before I install ubuntu so, How do I do that?

Comment: This is a general computing question about how to backup Windows on a laptop that does not have Ubuntu installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Download the free Clonezilla iso and install it on a CD/DVD or download the zip file and install it on a USB stick. Then boot from the CD/DVD or stick and follow the instructions. https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php